# Manage a process inside a cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to manage a process inside a cmd file. My cmd will launch an other cmd file and i would like the update status, ... For example, i would like to write the date when the other process is closed.

So, i tried :

```
rem %process% is the path to my cmd file
start "Process" %process%
```

Is there any way to manage the started process ?

I tried to use :

```
for /F "TOKENS=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %process%"') do (
    set MyPID=%%b
)
```

The problem is that the process is a cmd file so the IMAGENAME will be "cmd.exe".

Any solutions ?

Comment: Why not just `CALL` the other batch file and when it is done processing, control will return to the calling batch file at which time you can determine the date and time.

Comment: Because i would like to check the cmd file execution and for example to interrupt the process when i want. So i need to not block the script to scan the process activity.

Answer (score 2):

it will be easier for you to get the pid when you are starting the process.
You can do this with `WMIC` command (though it's a little bit cumbersome):

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=5 tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('WMIC process call create "notepad.exe"^,"c:\"') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=;= " %%# in ("%%a") do if not defined pid set "pid=%%#"
)

echo %pid%
```

You can use also [**this ready to use script**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/ProcessesUtils/StartPID.bat) which can spare you some work (hope the help message is descriptive enough)

Answer (score 2):

instead of IMAGENAME look for WINDOWTITLE (you defined that as a parameter to `start`):

```
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq "Process"
```

use this in your existing `for` loop.

you can add `/v` to `tasklist` to get a verbose output, but you don't really need it for this task.

Comment: Oh that's nice because i've got an unique ID. Well, i've got 2 solutions, thank you !